# How to combine OR , AND in one filter formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

```
=filter('CASES LIST'!C:S,'CASES LIST'!Q:Q="admission",len('CASES LIST'!S:S))
```

I have in the sheet column Q - has "admission", "consultation", other items in dropdown list.

In column S- other dropdown list as well.

In column R- drop down list

I want to filter data based on either of these two criteria:

1- Column Q="admission" **AND** column S is not empty

2- **OR** Column Q= "consultation"

If either of these criteria is met, the row C:S, will be copied to the desired sheet

I made this formula, but it doesn't seem working

```
=filter('CASES LIST'!C:S,'CASES LIST'!Q:Q="admission",len('CASES LIST'!S:S))+('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="consultation")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following query formula (adjusting ranges to your needs), instead of the filter you already use.

```
=QUERY({P1:S},"where Col2='admission' AND Col4<>'' OR Col2='consultation' ",0)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. If not, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.